# Save multiple rows in MySQL database using PDO, jQuery and Bootstrap

Tags: php, jquery, html, pdo

I'm creating an invoice. I really want to know how to add table rows with text fields using jQuery and PDO product description and prices into the database.

[This is the picture HTML form I want to add to database with PDO.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mDP5.gif)

This is the add table row added

```
//adds extra table rows
var i=$('table#invoiceTable tr').length;
$("#addmore").on('click',function(){
    html = '<tr id="row'+count+'">';
    html += '<td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="productCode" name="data['+i+'][product_id]" id="itemNo_'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt itemName_1" autocomplete="off"></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="productName" name="data['+i+'][product_name]" id="itemName_'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" name="data['+i+'][price]" id="price_'+i+'" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" name="data['+i+'][quantity]" id="quantity_'+i+'" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" name="data['+i+'][total]" id="total_'+i+'" class="form-control totalLinePrice" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
    html += '</tr>';
    $('table#invoiceTable').append(html);
    i++;
});
```

PDO code I want to make work:

```
//check if error array is empty, if yes process form data and insert record
    if(empty($form_errors)){
        //collect form data and store in variables
        $customername = $_POST['customername'];
        $customeraddr = $_POST['customeraddres'];
        $invoN = $_POST['invoiceNo'];
        $invoDa = $_POST['invoiceDate'];
        $product_Id = $_POST['product_id'];
        $product_desc = $_POST['product_name'];
        $product_Price = $_POST['price'];
        $product_quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
        $product_Total = $_POST['total'];

        try{

            //create SQL insert statement
            $sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO invoices (IvoiceToN, Address, invoiceNo, invoiceDate, _Id, Desc, Product_Price, Quantity, total)
                                        VALUES (:IvoiceToN, :Address, :invoiceNo, :invoiceDate, :Id, :Desc, :Price, :Quantity, :total)";

            //use PDO prepared to sanitize data
            $statement = $db->prepare($sqlInsert);

            //add the data into the database
            $statement->execute(array(':IvoiceToN' => $customername, ':clientAddress' => $customeraddr, ':invoiceNo' => $invoN, ':invoiceDate'=> $invoDa, ':Product_Id' => $product_Id, ':Desc' => $product_desc, ':Price' => $product_Price, ':Product_Quantity' => $product_quantity, ':total' => $product_Total));
```

Comment: You can loop the $pdo->execute with different values to insert them into the database, also you can get multiple $_POST parameters with same name when you use name="customername[uniqueid]" and access the array from php like this: $customerArray = $_POST['customername'];

Comment: thank you very much for your help can you spell to me little bit more how to do it?

Comment: Yeah I, mocked up an answer based on your code

Answer (score 0):

Given your current html this is how you would loop it:

```
$data = array();
if(count($_POST['data']) > 0){
    foreach($_POST['data'] as $key => $array){//get the "data" array in $_POST, loop through it and validate it
        $row = array();
        //$row['customername'] = strip_tags(trim(strval($array['customername'])));
        //$row['customeraddres'] = strip_tags(trim(strval($array['customeraddres'])));
        //$row['invoiceNo'] = strip_tags(trim(strval($array['invoiceNo'])));
        //$row['invoiceDate'] = strip_tags(trim(strval($array['invoiceDate'])));// you may want to format this and check if it's a valid date
        $row['product_description'] = strip_tags(trim(strval($array['product_name'])));
        $row['product_id'] = intval($array['product_id']);
        $row['price'] = is_numeric($array['price']) ? $array['price'] : false;
        $row['quantity'] = intval($array['quantity']);
        $row['total'] = is_numeric($array['total']) ? $array['total'] : false;//you need better validation of data here propably
        $data[$key] = $row;
    }
}
try{
if(count($data) > 0){
    //create SQL insert statement
    $sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO invoices (IvoiceToN, Address, invoiceNo, invoiceDate, _Id, Desc, Product_Price, Quantity, total)
                                        VALUES (:IvoiceToN, :Address, :invoiceNo, :invoiceDate, :Id, :Desc, :Price, :Quantity, :total)";

    $statement = $db->prepare($sqlInsert);//use PDO prepared to sanitize data
    foreach($data as $key => $array){//add the data into the database
         $statement->execute(array(':IvoiceToN' => $array['customername'], ':clientAddress' => $array['customeraddres'], ':invoiceNo' => $array['invoiceNo'], ':invoiceDate'=> $array['invoiceDate'], ':Product_Id' => $array['product_id'], ':Desc' => $array['product_description'], ':Price' => $array['price'], ':Product_Quantity' => $array['quantity'], ':total' => $array['total']));
    }
}
```

Edit: I commented out the part where you get data which does not show on your html

Comment: thank you very much for your help I check the code just i get error An error occurred: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Comment: Add in your customername address invoiceno etc... in the execute line.
I can't assume how you get those.